# How to add style to imported ccs library?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-awesome, cloudflare

I try to improve GooglePageSpeed of my website https://agariogame.club/ and I have an issue (Avoid showing invisible text). [image: Text]
The problem is in a library that I use.
I use it from Cloudflare with code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

To [solve](https://web.dev/font-display/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown#how-to-avoid-showing-invisible-text) the problem I need to add this to the library.

```
font-display: swap;
```

This library uses font that I have an issue. 
[image: Text]

How can I add "font-display: swap;" to solve problem?

I have suggestions how to solve.
Simply download and fix it, use locally. But it will decrease perfomance.

Comment: Simply override the unwanted code with your own code in the main document 101. Have you tried that already?

Comment: I've added next to my index.html
`<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
            src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2');
            font-display: swap !important;
        }
    </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

But this doesn't help.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If your problem stays, you will need to serve FontAwsome from you own server, with a modified `font-awesome.min.css`. Lots of companies/people do this. Even better: go to [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/) create a small font file with only the icons you need and serve that from your server, will be much smaller, much faster. This would be the recommended way. Oow, just saw, move the `<link>` loading FontAwsome **before** your style. Now it overrides your modification because you load it **after** your in doc style.

Comment: I've moved <link> above <style>. But nothing changed.
In style I've added 2 raws. `font-family:'FontAwesome' !important;font-display: swap !important;}` But it doesn't overrides. So the last option is to create own `awesome.min.css`?

Comment: The recommended solution always is (always) to create a small subset of the icons you need and serve that version yourself (smaller css included).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've solved problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can either download the desktop version of font-awesome and use it. It will also improve the speed as you can use only the icon you want in SVG manner.

To do so you need to add the `CSS` file called `all.min.css`(This will come with the download of font-awesome). The `all.min.css` file should be in a folder called `css` and out of that folder you should have another folder called `webfonts`(You will get it with font awesome download).

To download visit: https://fontawesome.com/download on the front page you will get two options for download one for web/Download and second for desktop. You will download the web version. The desktop version only contains SVG. You will get a zip file which will have all the required files you need.

Folder Placement:

Main folder --

Folder 1 - css:  Files(1):  all.min.css

Folder 2 - webfonts:  Files(15):  ......

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! I did as you said, but `all.min.css` uses big fonts collections like `fa-brands-400.woff2`. How can I use only specific SVGs insted? What should I write to my css?

Comment: To do so download the other file -- the desktop version. You will get all the svgs and then you can add them with `<img>` tag. And give them height and width through CSS.

Comment: This way you will get all the free icons on font-awesome as SVG on your pc.

Comment: Thank you so much!